# How to remover border <body> with blur effect?

Tags: jquery, dom, blur

I'm creating a blur effect when someone clicks on a button to bring up a popup. I've read other places that the easiest way to remove the border of the border of the blurred object is to add negative margin to the applied object. I've tried that, but haven't had any luck when it's applied to the  tag.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

JQUERY

```
$(function () {
    $('#general').click(function () {
        $('#general-p').fadeIn(1000);
        $(document.body).addClass('blur');         
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.blur {
     -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
     -moz-filter: blur(10px);
     -o-filter: blur(10px);
     -ms-filter: blur(10px);
     filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: What's happening instead?

Comment: There's a blurred edge to the <body> after the action is executed. It's exactly what is supposed to happen, but I want to get rid of that edge. Here's an example of the edge I'm talking about: https://webkit.org/blog-files/backdrop-filters/backdrop_mixed_1x.jpg. Here's what I want it to look like: https://www.google.com/search?q=filter+blur+example&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkmJeR1_rSAhWFh1QKHYG5A3cQ_AUICSgC&biw=1536&bih=771#imgrc=KLCZnuylV7ILOM:&spf=259